# "undefined method `metadata' for.." rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, undefined, mass-assignment

Hi i have this problem running the spec file.
this is the reparator model:

```
class Reparator < User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :private_reparator, :type => Boolean, :default => true
  field :brand_name, :type => String
  field :year_of_experience, :type => Integer, :default => 1

  has_many :reparations
  has_many :skills

  validates_presence_of :skills, :year_of_experience
  validates :year_of_experience, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0}
end
```

This is the skill model:

```
class Skill
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, :type => String

  belongs_to :reparator

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name

end
```

This is the controller:

```
class ReparatorsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @reparators = Reparator.all
    respond_with @reparators
  end

  def show
    @reparator = Reparator.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @reparator
  end

  def create
    @reparator = Reparator.new(params[:reparator])
    @reparator.skills = params[:skills]
    if @reparator.save
      respond_with @reparator
    else
      respond_with @reparator.errors
    end
  end

  def update
    @reparator = Reparator.find(params[:id])

    if @reparator.update_attributes(params[:reparator])
      respond_with @reparator
    else
      respond_with @reparator.errors
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @reparator = Reparator.find(params[:id])
    @reparator.destroy
    respond_with "Correctly destroyed"
  end

end
```

And this is the spec file for this controller (i'll just put the test that does't pass):

```
it "Should create an reparator" do
      valid_skills = [FactoryGirl.create(:skill).id, FactoryGirl.create(:skill).id]
      valid_attributes = {:name => "Vianello",
                          :email => "maremma@gmail.com",
                          :address => "viale ciccio",
                          :private_reparator => true
                          }
      post :create, :reparator => valid_attributes, :skills => valid_skills
      assigns(:reparator).should be_a Reparator
      assigns(:reparator).should be_persisted
    end
```

And this is the skill Factory girl:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :skill do
    sequence(:name) {|n| "skill#{n}"}
  end
end
```

Comment: It gives me this error: undefined method `id' for "500d3e15670b4d0a32000027":String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a typo in your spec. `post :create, :reparator => valid_attributes, :skills => skills_ttributes` should be `post :create, :reparator => valid_attributes, :skills => skills_attributes` instead.

Comment: You are right, i edited it, it was a typo and now i've got a different error

Answer (score 0):

The bad line is this one

```
@reparator.skills = params[:skills]
```

`params[:skills]` is an array of strings (the ids that have been passed) but the `skills=` method expects to be given actual instances of `Skill` and so blows up.

As well as `skills=`, mongoid also gives you a `skill_ids=` method which allows you to change which objects are associated by just assigning an array of ids. Alternatively, load the skills object your self and then to `@reparator.skills = skills`

Comment: i already tried that but it tells me undefined method `skill_ids' for #<Reparator:0x007f966d339ab8> anytime i call FactoryGirl.create with this code (regarding skill_ids) "after_build {|reparator| reparator.skill_ids << FactoryGirl.create(:skill).id}"

Comment: That method is only in mongoid 3, sounds like you're using mongoid 2, so you'll just have do do without it.

Comment: mmmm i don't think so, i'm using it in others specs but with that one does't work!

Comment: I can't anwers, i found out what was the problem, i had to edit the relationship from has_many and belongo_to to has_and_belongs_to_many both of them! and then i could find the skill_ids array!!